# How to use MySQL built-in functions in Laravel DB::raw()

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using an sql query like the following with the MySQL built in ADDDATE() function in Laravel Query Builder to increment the date by 1 day.

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table
        SET date_col = ADDDATE(date_col, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        WHERE id = {$the_id}";

DB::update($sql);
```

This is working fine and there is no reason to really change it.  However, I first tried to use Query Builder with DB::raw as follows.

```
DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('id',$the_id)
   ->update(['date_col'=> DB::raw(ADDDATE(date_col, INTERVAL 1 DAY)]);
```

Is it possible to use the MySQL functions in this way?  Is my syntax wrong or what?

Comment: You can use this also why go for raw... DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('id',$the_id)
   ->update(['date_col'=> carbon::now()->addDays(1)])

Comment: Not possible because the date value is coming from the database. it is not today's date

Comment: Then save database date_col value in variable after that add one day using php date function and pass this final vairable inquery

Comment: @bipin Why do two queries when only one is necessary?

Comment: @skribe yes you right I m just suggesting possiblity

Comment: I'd bet your code threw a very obvious syntax error, which you should've shared with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the content of `DB:raw` between quotes because you add a raw string that will be sent to the MySQL server.

```
DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('id',$the_id)
   ->update(['date_col'=> DB::raw('ADDDATE(date_col, INTERVAL 1 DAY)')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can this way.

```
   DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('id',$the_id)
   ->update(['date_col'=> DB::raw("DATE_ADD(date_col, INTERVAL 1 DAY)")]);
```

Also, the `mysql` function is [DATE_ADD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) not `ADDDATE`.

Comment: "When invoked with the INTERVAL form of the second argument, ADDDATE() is a synonym for DATE_ADD()." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate